# Subset of $A$ of arbirary small measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu(A)>0$. Show that for arbitrary small $\epsilon>0$, there exists a subset $B$ of $A$ such that 
\begin{align}
0 < \mu(B) < \epsilon
\end{align}

Assume that $\mu$ is not an attomic measure (e.g. Direct measure).
Thank you. Any help with this will be appreciated.

Comment: What are the assumptions on $\mu$? E.g. is it the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: No. Just any measure.

Comment: Well then it's false: just take $\mu$ to be a Dirac measure.

Comment: I edited the comment. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true for all measures.  For example, we may define
$$
\delta(A) =
\begin{cases}
1 & 0 \in A\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

---

**Hint:** Suppose that $A$ is bounded.  Show that the function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ given by
$$
f(t) = \mu(A \cap (-\infty,t))
$$
is continuous.  Apply the intermediate value theorem.

Generalize this to the unbounded case by breaking $A$ into bounded pieces.

---

For general non-atomic measures, see the sketch of the proof [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(measure_theory)#Non-atomic_measures).

Comment: What you wrote is only true for Lebesgue measure only, right?

Comment: And any measure absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure.  Note that your statement will not hold true for measures such as the dirac measure.

Comment: I edited the comment. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Thank you for the last comment very help full.